# Como inserir um elemento entre dois elementos?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, table

## Explicação:

Tenho uma `<div>` pai que contém duas `<div>` filhas, porém eu gostaria de inserir uma `<table>` utilizando javascript, entre, ou seja, no meio dessas duas `<div>` filhas que já existem na `<div>` pai.

Porém a minha `<table>` é uma string que contem o código HTML como valor.

Código da minha `<table>` como string:

```
var HTMLString = '<table id="teste"><tbody id="appender"><tr class="header"><td class="cod">Código</td> <td class="nome">Nome</td><td class="tipo">Cidade - Estado</td></tr></tbody></table>';
```

HTML da div pai e das div filhas:

```html
<div id=elementoPai>
  <div id="fixedHeader_outer">
      <div id="fixedHeader">conteudo</div>
  </div>
<!-- quero que a HTMLString se transforme num html que apareça aqui no meio das duas -->
  <div id="pnlOpcoes_outer">
    <div id="pnlOpcoes">conteudo</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## [Exemplo no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fu7h3/)

## Pergunta:

Como eu poderia fazer isto? Gostaria de várias soluções, citando as vantagens e desvantagens das mesmas, podendo utilizar do jQuery ou não

Comment: Tem a tag jQuery... é isso mesmo ou é pra fazer em JS puro?

Comment: pode ser em jQuery também, porém é necessário ? é mais rápido ? qual a utilidade de usar jQuery neste contexto? fica ao seu critério porem eu aceito

Comment: Uma vantagem do jQuery, considerando as respostas, é uma linha de código para quatro com JS puro.

Comment: @PauloRoberto, Javascript é sempre mais rápido que jQuery, pode porem ser mais simples pôr a funcionar em Browsers diferentes com jQuery

Comment: jQuery é javascript, não outra linguagem. A coisa tá tão feia que já vi navegador com jQuery pré-carregado, pra sair mais rápido.

Answer (score 9):

Em JavaScript puro você pode fazer assim:

```
var HTMLString = '<table id="teste"><tbody id="appender"><tr class="header"><td class="cod">Código</td> <td class="nome">Nome</td><td class="tipo">Cidade - Estado</td></tr></tbody></table>';

var ref = document.getElementById('pnlOpcoes_outer');
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = HTMLString;
ref.parentElement.insertBefore(div.firstChild, ref);
```

<sup>[Demo no jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fu7h3/4/)</sup>

Isto funciona neste caso porque o seu `HTMLString` só contém um element solto na raiz. Uma opção mais genérica:

```
var ref = document.getElementById('pnlOpcoes_outer');
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = HTMLString;
while(div.firstChild) {
    ref.parentElement.insertBefore(div.firstChild, ref);
}
```

<sup>[Demo no jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fu7h3/5/)</sup>

Tem também uma opção meio obscura, mas compatível até com browsers bem antigos, utilizando [`Element.insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.insertAdjacentHTML) (dica do Emerson Rocha Luiz):

```
var ref = document.getElementById('pnlOpcoes_outer');
ref.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", HTMLString);
```

<sup>[Demo no jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fu7h3/6/)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Pega a primeira div e insere depois dela:

```
$('#fixedHeader_outer').after(HTMLString);
```

Quero participar do codegolf: se não quiser usar jQuery há essa opção, tão curta quanto a original:

```
fixedHeader_outer.outerHTML += HTMLString;
```

Como foi pedido, a [tabela de compatibilidade](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.outerHTML#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: Ganhou por 7 segundos...

Comment: Não se sinta morto @utluiz estou ancioso para ver a sua resposta =p

Comment: @PauloRoberto Estou me referindo ao Miguel... acho que nesse caso não tenho nada a acrescentar, considerando a resposta do bfavaretto

Comment: ah sim, agora entendi. :)

Comment: A resposta é a mesma: isso é muito trivial. Tipo, muito.

Comment: Dúvida: já tem três respostas, pela tag o OP pediu jQuery mas todo mundo quer inovar. Edito minha resposta para participar desse codegolf? Nada tão simples quanto `fixedHeader_outer.outerHTML += HTMLString;`

Comment: sim com certeza @GustavoRodrigues eu justamente quero é isto, várias soluções, mais tarde irei colocar todas no jsperf e ver qual a mais rapida =p

Comment: Poderia editar a resposta com a compatibilidade do método utilizando `.outerHTML`? gostaria de saber se este método é compativel com todos os navegadores utilizados atualmente

Answer (score 3):

Pelas tags pressuponho que vocês está utilizando jQuery. Então aqui está a solução:

```
$('#fixedHeader_outer').after(HTMLString);
```

Se você não estiver usando jQuery, ficaria assim:

```
var referenceNode = document.getElementById('fixedHeader_outer');
var newNode = document.createElement('table');
newNode.innerHTML = '<tbody id="appender"><tr class="header"><td class="cod">Código</td> <td class="nome">Nome</td><td class="tipo">Cidade - Estado</td></tr></tbody>';

referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
```