# Criar elemento entre elementos filhos de um mesmo Pai

Tags: javascript, html, css3

Conforme o código abaixo:

```js
var ul = document.getElementsByTagName('ul');
var ref = ul.item(0).children;
var saida = '';

  for (i = 0; i <= ref.length; i++) {
if (i == 0) {
 var HTMLString = "<div style='background-color: blue; width: 60px; height: 60px;'>";
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = HTMLString;
    ref[i].parentElement.insertBefore(div.firstChild, ref[i]);
}
if (i == 11) {
 var HTMLString = "</div><div style='background-color: red; width: 60px; height: 60px;'>";
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = HTMLString;
    ref[i].parentElement.insertBefore(div.firstChild, ref[i]);
}
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="div1">
  <ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>13</li>
  <li>14</li>
  <li>15</li>
  <li>16</li>
  <li>17</li>
  <li>18</li>
  <li>19</li>
  <li>20</li>
  <li>21</li>
  <li>22</li>
  <li>23</li>
  <li>24</li>
  <li>25</li>
  </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Seria possível abrir a `<div>` antes do primeiro elemento `<li>` e fechar ela após o 10º elemento `<li>` ??

Se sim, como fazer?

---

*Obs.: Conforme o `<script>` que eu criei ele cria o elemento `<div>` e fecha no mesmo lugar ... 

Usei o conceito da [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6553/como-inserir-um-elemento-entre-dois-elementos#6557) desta [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6553/como-inserir-um-elemento-entre-dois-elementos).*

Comment: Podes explicar o que queres fazer como produto final? Quebrar sintaxe de ul > li com divs não me parece muito bom.

Comment: Pois bem, na hora de imprimir a página que contem esses elementos, eles acabam sendo impressos em separado na outra página, pela quantidade gerada, daí pensei em dividir esses elementos em `DIV`s aplicando um `float: left` para organizar eles lado a lado, quando chegar a uma certa quantia, entende ?

Comment: Quem sabe seria interessante eu dar um `appendChild` nos elementos até a quantia desejada para a `DIV` que eu criei e depois remover os elementos que foram copiados ?