# Adicionar Elementos com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

Estou recebendo o erro:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The
>   node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of
>   this node.

Quando tento inserir uma div depois de outra usando JavaScript.

```
function verificaHierarquia(e) {
    var valor = $(e).val(),
        valor2 = $(e).children(':selected').data("valor2");

    if (valor2 == 1) {
        var divSupervisor = document.createElement("div");
        divSupervisor.id = "divSupervisor";
        divSupervisor.className = "col-lg-6 mb-3";

        var divAtual = document.getElementById("divSenha");
        divAtual.insertBefore(divSupervisor, divSenha);

        document.getElementById("divSupervisor").innerHTML =
            '<label for="sup">Sup</label>\n'+
            '<input type="text" name="sup" class="form-control">';
    }
}
```

Comment: Resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6553/como-inserir-um-elemento-entre-dois-elementos

Answer (score 0):

O segundo parâmetro do método [`Node.insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) é um nodo de referência para o JS saber em qual parte do elemento `parent` será inserido.

Pela exceção recebida, me parece que `divSenha` não é filho de `divAtual`, dessa maneira o JS não sabe onde inserir o novo nodo.